# How to replace a string in a list with another string?

Tags: python, list, insert

How can I take a string and insert it into a list in the place of another string that is already there (so I don't get out of range error)?

example:

```
l = ["rock", "sand", "dirt"]
l.remove[1]
l.insert(1, "grass")
```

is there an easier way to do it than this? What do I do if I have an empty list and the order matters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is:

```
>>> l = ["rock", "sand", "dirt"]
>>> l[1] = "grass"
>>> l
['rock', 'grass', 'dirt']
>>>
```

Lists support direct replacement in Python via `list[index] = value`.

Comment: @user2976947 - Happy to help!  Don't forget to accept an answer (click the tick) when the system lets you.

Answer (score 4):

you can also directly replace the element: `l[1] = 'grass'`

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are unsure of the index of the item you would like to replace you just use:
Say the item you want to replace is "dirt", you'd just go:

```
rightIndex = l.index("dirt")
l[rightIndex] = "grass
```

This will replace "dirt" with "grass" if you are unsure about the index of "grass" in list "l".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at an arbitrary list, you might not know if the item is in the list or what index it is. You might first check that the item is in the list, then look for the index, so that you can replace it. The following example would do this for the all elements in a list that matches what you want to replace:

```
def replace_list_item(old, new, l):
   '''
   Given a list with an old and new element, replace all elements
   that match the old element with the new element, and return the list.
   e.g. replace_list_item('foo', 'bar', ['foo', 'baz', 'foo'])
   => ['bar', 'baz', 'bar']
   '''
   while old in l: # check for old item, otherwise index gives a value error
       index = l.index(old)
       l[index] = new
   return l
```

then:

```
l = ["rock", "sand", "dirt", "sand"]
replace_list_item('sand', 'grass', l)
```

returns:

```
['rock', 'grass', 'dirt', 'grass']
```